# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]

Tags: php, apache, sqlite, apache2

I'm trying to connect to an SQLite database using PHP for a login page. I want to compare the "username" and "password" input in the login page with the one's stored in the database and if it matches then redirect to a new page (welcome.php). My code is:

```
<?php
    class MyDB extends SQLite3 {

        function __construct() {
            $this->open('test.db');
        }

    }

    $db = new MyDB();
    if(!$db) {
        echo $db->lastErrorMsg();
    }
    else {
        echo "Opened database successfully\n";
    }

    include('config.php');
    $username = $_POST['Username'];
    $password = $_POST['Password'];
    $db = new PDO('sqlite:db/test.db');
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM login where username='$username' && password='$password]'");
    $stmt->execute(array($username, $password));
    if($stmt->fetchAll()){
?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.location="welcome.php";
        </script>

<?php
    }
    else {
?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert("incorrect username or password");
        </script>

<?php
    }
```

After I run this code, I get a blank validate.php page which says "Opened database successfully".

The error log file in the Apache server shows this message:

```
[Fri Sep 07 12:13:17.037251 2018] [:error] [pid 16529] [client      192.168.0.110:44534] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]   [14] unable to open database file in /var/www/html/validate.php:16\nStack  trace:\n#0 /var/www/html/validate.php(16):  PDO->__construct('sqlite:db/test....')\n#1 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www  /html/validate.php on line 16, referer: http://192.168.0.110/
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: 1. instead of ding all class and stuff directly do `$db = new SQLite3('test.db');` .2.change your `prepare` query like this and check:-`$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM login where username=? AND password=?");`Also did you saved plain password? It will create bigger issues.

Comment: How can this fix `unable to open database file`?

Comment: @AlivetoDie did what you said. It's still giving the same error

Comment: @amogh389  i have added some new point in my recent edit. check once again

Comment: @AlivetoDie the PDO error's gone but I'm still getting 4 new errors: 1) PHP Warning:  include(config.php): failed to open stream 2) PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening 'config.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') 3) PHP Warning:  SQLite3::prepare(): Unable to prepare statement: 1, no such column: password 4) PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function execute() on boolean in /var/www/html/validate.php